# Javascript - how do I minimise this code example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

a quick question.

At the moment I have 12 links on a page, and 12 corresponding javascript codes that run when a each button is clicked.

I know 100% there must be a method of having 1 javascript code and the link passing a variable  to it, so I don't have to have 12 different codes.

EG. Here is a link I'm currently using:

```
<a href="#" id="button1">Anatomical Pathology</a>
```

And the Javascript function that is run when the link is clicked loads some html from a php script into a div which is previously defined as level2:

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    level2.load("http://hello/script.php?url=poodles");
});
```

What I'd really like to do is something like this with the link:

```
<a href="#" id="button1" passurl="poodles">Anatomical Pathology</a>
```

And the function something like this, so I only need the 1 function not 12:

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    level2.load("http://hello/script.php?url=' + passurl + '");
});
```

How do I go about getting the data from the link tag into javascript, and also how do I add this passed variable into the url I want the javascript to pull data in from?

Comment: You probably should add a class to each button, so you can write a selector like `$('.mybutton')` and assign a method to all buttons at once.

Answer (score 8):

`passurl` isn't standard attribute, you should use `data-passurl`

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    var passurl = $(this).data('passurl'); // or $(this).attr('data-passurl');
    level2.load("http://hello/script.php?url=" + passurl);
});
```

Comment: Typo: `attr-passurl` should be `data-passurl`. Furthermore, jQuery supports data attributes through the `data` method: `$(this).data("passurl")`.

Comment: If JavaScript is a requirement for the application to run, there's no danger in using the href to store the URL. You can preventDefault on it to avoid typical link behaviour. Then there's no need for a data attribute. I guess it's not really any better or worse, but rather than having # for the href, might as well use it.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you utilize your hash there...

```
<a href="#/poodles" class="button">Anatomical Pathology</a>
```

In your script

```
$(".button").each(function() {
  // get the hash and extract the part we want store it in this enclosure
  var url = $(this).attr("href").replace(/^#\//, "");
  // create a click handler that loads the url
  $(this).click(function() {
    level2.load("http://hello/script.php?url=" + url);
  });
});
```

This also brings about the possibility to extrapolate from that so that a hash passed through the url can also operate the script loading...

Comment: Gotcha, will give this a try!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rel attributte (or any data- attributes if your using HTML5 Doctype) to save your URL and add a class to the links you want to execute your callback.

```
<a href="#" class="button" rel="your-url">Anatomical Pathology</a>
```

Your Callback:

```
$('a.button').click(function() {
    level2.load("http://hello/script.php?url=' + $(this).attr('rel') + '");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more extensible solution you could consider making a json structure for your urls:

```
var urls = [{
    "poodle":{
        "url":"http://hello/script.php?url=poodle",
        "someOtherData":"data"
    },
    "otherDog":{
        "url":"http://hello/script.php?url=otherDog",
        "someOtherData":"data"
    }
}];
```

You would store some sort of key somewhere in your HTML element:

```
<a href="#" rel="poodle">Anatomical Pathology</a>
```

Then you would leverage this data structure in your functional code:

```
$('a').click(function () {
    var key = $(this).attr('rel');
    level2.load(urls[key].url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Stuie, add a class to the links so that you can target them all at once. However, I don't see the need to fool with the hash, and I wouldn't add a bunch of click events either. Just delegate once and you're done:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <a href="poodles" class="button">Poodles</a>
  <a href="schnausers" class= "button">Schnausers</a>
</div>
```

and the JS:

```
$('#wrapper').delegate('a.button', 'click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var passurl = $(this).attr("href");
  level2.load("http://hello/script.php?url=" + passurl); // assuming "level2" is valid from elsewhere  
});
```

Where I have "#wrapper" you would designate any unique selector that is an ancestor of all your links. It's an element that listens for clicks on the a.button elements within.